# Javascript passing "this" from prototype to another function

Tags: javascript

I am struggling with the passing of context "this" from a prototype function in a controller to a private function(s) in the same controller.Browser console throws an error "Cannot read property 'callSomeService' of undefined". My code looks like-

```
MyController.prototype.somemethod = function (){
      return somePrivateFunction()
              .then(function (resultsFromsomePrivateFunction){
                  return someAnotherPrivateFunction(resultsFromsomePrivateFunction)
       });
}

function somePrivateFunction(){
   this.callSomeService()
         .then(function (results) {
             return results 
           });
}

function someAnotherPrivateFunction(){
   //dosomething
}
```

Can someone please help ?

Comment: I don't see anything angular here

Comment: `somePrivateFunction.call(this)`.. Value of this is determined by __how__ function is called, not by __where__ function is called...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `call` or `apply` to set the context.

```
return somePrivateFunction.call(this).then(...)
```

OR

```
return somePrivateFunction.apply(this).then(...)
```

Comment: that works but I am left with one more in the code                                      return somePrivateFunction.call(this).then(...)

Comment: that works but I am left with one more question , "this" again looses its reference in the then after here. What would be best approach to handle that ? Should I assign this to a local variable like self and use it?                                                              return somePrivateFunction.call(this).then(...)

Comment: If I understand correctly You cannot access `this` inside `function (resultsFromsomePrivateFunction)` which you are passing inside `then`. If that is the case, you can create an independent function and then pass it inside `then` using bind, Something like: `return somePrivateFunction().then(newlyCreatedThenFunction.bind(this))` where the `newlyCreatedThenFunction` is `function (resultsFromsomePrivateFunction)`. Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

You are simply calling `somePrivateFunction()`, for which `this` will be either the global object, or `undefined` in strict mode. You either need to use `.call` or `.apply` to explicitly set the `this` value:

```
MyController.prototype.somemethod = function (){
    return somePrivateFunction.call(this)
        .then( /* ... */ );
}
```

Or pass the object you want as an argument:

```
MyController.prototype.somemethod = function (){
    return somePrivateFunction(this)
        .then( /* ... */ );
}

function somePrivateFunction(that){
    that.callSomeService()
    /* ... */
}
```